# Вывод данных массива на экран React

Tags: массивы, reactjs, state

У меня есть React приложение. В компонента страницы водителя (DriverWay) я получил все заказы с базы данных и записал их в orderList. Я пытаюсь вывести данные на экран через компонент Order, но не получается. Массив не пустой, я проверял

DriverWay:

```
const orderList = [];
const DriverWay = () => {

  const listen = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUid(user.email.split('@')[0]);
    }
  });

  const db = getDatabase();
  const dbRef = ref(db, 'orders/');

  function handleOnClick() {
    onValue(
      dbRef,
      (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          orderList.push(childSnapshot.val());
        });
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );
  }

  handleOnClick();


  orderList.map((item) => console.log(item));

  return (
    <div className={styles.driver__way__block}>
      <MapWithRoute />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        onClick={handleOnClick}
        width={19.9375}
        height={3.6875}
        bgc="FFE500"
        btnText="Показать заказы"
        btnTextColor="FFF"
      />
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100vw',
          height: '100vh',
          zIndex: 9999999,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          top: 0,
        }}
      >
        {orderList.map((order) => (
          <Order
            key={order}
            nowGeo={order.nowGeolocation}
            endGeo={order.endGeolocation}
            uid={order.uid}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Order:

```
const Order = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Now geo: {props.nowGeo}</h1>
      <h2>End geo: {props.endGeo}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Order;
```

App.jsx:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/driver-way" element={<DriverWay uid={driverId} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Получение данных и запись я упустил. Также пробовал просто вывести элементы массива с помощью `.map (orderList.map((item) => console.log(item));)`. Логи пустые, на экране ничего

Comment: Ваш `orderList` должен быть в состоянии компонента, иначе реакт не видит изменений и рендерит исходные данные(пустой массив)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, которым вы наполняете orderList.

Comment: @SwaD, внес изменения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я вижу вы не используете State

Используйте State чтобы компонент обновлялся при изменении массива

```
const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([])
```

При выполнении запроса нужно вызвать setOrderlist(Новый массив) чтобы компонент перерендерился

Используйте useEffect для разового обновления компонента:

```
useEffect(function, [])
```

Внутри функции напишите fetch и setOrderList для state

**Правка

Вынесите этот кусок кода в App.jsx:

```
const listen = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUid(user.email.split('@')[0]);
    }
  });

  const db = getDatabase();
  const dbRef = ref(db, 'orders/');
const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([])
  function handleOnClick() {
    onValue(
      dbRef,
      (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          setOrderList(...orderList,childSnapshot.val());
        });
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );
  }

  handleOnClick();
```

Передайте в DriverWay orderList как props

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151416/discussion-on-answer-by-anvarjon------react); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Grundy может это и правильно, только вот ни спрашивающий, ни отвечающий чат не увидят, репутации маловато...

Comment: Согласен. И опыта чтобы туда перейти тоже...

Comment: @SwaD, увидят, при переносе им автоматически явно выдаются права.

Comment: @Anvarjon, постаточно перейти по ссылке [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151416/discussion-on-answer-by-anvarjon------react) и следовать дальнейшим указаниям

Answer (score 0):

Ваш orderList должен быть переменной состояния компонента, в таком случае React сможет отслеживать изменения и перерисовывать данные на странице.

Так же, инициализацию соединения с БД(или что это) лучше убрать из компонента, иначе каждое изменение данных внутри компонента будет инициироваться новое соединение.

В дополнение, вызов функции `handleOnClick` внутри компонента приведет к повторному запросу данных, повторному вызову функции и далее все зациклится.

```
const db = getDatabase();
const dbRef = ref(db, 'orders/');

const DriverWay = () => {
  // Создаем переменную состояния
  const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([]);
  // Функция вызывается по клику
  function handleOnClick() {
    onValue(
      dbRef,
      (snapshot) => {
        const newOrderList = []; // Создаем новый массив
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          // Пушим данные
          newOrderList.push(childSnapshot.val());
        });
        // Сохраняем данные в переменную состояния, что приведет к перерисовке компонента
        setOrderList(newOrderList);
      },
      {
        onlyOnce: true,
      }
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.driver__way__block}>
      <MapWithRoute />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        onClick={handleOnClick}
        width={19.9375}
        height={3.6875}
        bgc="FFE500"
        btnText="Показать заказы"
        btnTextColor="FFF"
      />
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100vw',
          height: '100vh',
          zIndex: 9999999,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          top: 0,
        }}
      >
        {orderList.map((order) => (
          <Order
            key={order}
            nowGeo={order.nowGeolocation}
            endGeo={order.endGeolocation}
            uid={order.uid}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```